# swift notify if wkwebview cant load page

Tags: swift, wkwebview

i am writing an app, that includes a `WKWebView` which displays a page of our intranet. The intranet can only be accessed if the deviced is connected to our WiFi. If it is not, the view remains blank. How can i catch this case, so that i can display a message like "could not load the page". neither `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)` nor `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error)` is called.

Comment: Have you set the webView.delegate = self ?

Comment: sure and if the device is connected to the wifi, the function gets called correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one delegate method

```
webView:didFailProvisionalNavigation:withError:
```

That is called when an error occurs while the web view is loading content.
See also the [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455637-webview?language=objc)